# PHP how to return a null json array if there is no data to show

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I've a situation here I've got a basket stored in session there is a delete item button on user end. I want to return a null array if there is not item in the array

Here is my PHP code

```
session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once('includes/requireonce.php');

if ( strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' ) :

    if(isset($_POST['removeItem'])){

        $itemToRemove = htmlspecialchars($_POST['removeItem']);

        if(count($_SESSION['order_array']) <= 1){
            unset($_SESSION['order_array']);
            print json_encode([null]);
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION['order_array'][$itemToRemove]);
            sort($_SESSION['order_array']);
            print json_encode($_SESSION['order_array']);
        }
    }
endif;
```

jQuery function that calls that code and prints the data on screen:

```
$('#fixedBasket').on('click', '.removeItemCLS', function() {
    var itemIndex = $(this).attr('id'),
        cart_total = 0;
    // console.log('remove Item new: ' + itemIndex);

    $.post("delete_item.php",
    {
        removeItem : itemIndex
    },
    function(data){
        if(data){
            $("#cart_result").empty();
            $(data).each(function(index,item) {
                output = setCartContent(index, item);
                cart_total += +item.price;
                $("#cart_result").append(output);
            });

            $("#cart_total").empty();
            $("#cart_total").html(cart_total.toFixed(2));
        }else{
            $("#cart_result").empty();
            $("#cart_total").empty();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

setCartContent below

```
function setCartContent(index, data){
    return '<div class="row">' + 
        '<div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" id="' + index + '" class="removeItemCLS"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a></div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-7">' + data.product_name + '</div>' + 
        '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="pull-right">' +  data.price + '</div></div>' + 
    '</div><br />';
}
```

I want to return a null and catch a null on jQuery side so if it is null just empty the div's

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: `print json_encode(array())` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
print json_encode([]);
```

that will return an empty or null array